# Не переведено сообщение, предлагающее закрыть вопрос как дубликат

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дубликаты

> A community member has suggested a similar question that may solve your problem.

> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Немного подправил ваш перевод и утвердил

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13773

Будет на сайте в свежих сборках. Текущая 2020.12.3.38123